# Mapping XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an *entity* that consists of **name**, **type**, and **number** elements. Unfortunately it's being rendered in the format that I do not want. I am not allowed to modify a code that renders that entity. The only thing I am allowed to do is to create a XSL file that transforms my input into a desirable output.

Let's say we have 3 entities. The XML file displays them in the wrong pattern. It displays a name of the *first* entity, name of the *second*, then of the *third*. Same pattern applies to type and number. It displays a type of the *first* entity, type of the *second*, then type of the *third* entity, and etc.

I want to output the entities in the more logical pattern, e.g. name of the *1st*, type of the *1st*, number of the *1st* entity. Followed by a name of the *2nd*, type of the *2nd*, number of the *2nd* entity, and etc. I also want to put each of these elements into an element called **Entity**.

So, for example, how would I transform the following XML input

```
<root>
    <Name>Harambe</Name>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Name>Mazda</Name>

    <Type>Ape</Type>
    <Type>Human</Type>
    <Type>Car</Type>

    <Number>1111</Number>
    <Number>2222</Number>
    <Number>3333</Number>
</root>
```

into this:

```
<root>
     <Entity>
         <Name>Harambe</Name>
         <Type>Ape</Type>
         <Number>1111</Number>
     </Entity>

     <Entity>
         <Name>John Smith</Name>
         <Type>Human</Type>
         <Number>2222</Number>
     </Entity>

     <Entity>
         <Name>Mazda</Name>
         <Type>Car</Type>
         <Number>3333</Number>
     </Entity>             
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Name">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <Entity>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::Type[$i] | following-sibling::Number[$i]"/>
            </Entity>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```